# Who are the three (different?) addressee's in verse (10:87)?

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, uloom-al-quran

First be aware that the issue can only be observed in the Arabic original as the verse (10:87) in its English translation looks like:

> And We inspired to Moses and his brother, "Settle your people in Egypt in houses and make your houses [facing the] qiblah and establish prayer and give good tidings to the believers."

But in fact as the verse starts the addressee's seem to be Musa and his brother only as in Arabic only the dual plural is used and tells them (Arabic and my commentary to show the linguistic issue):

> أَن تَبَوَّءَا لِقَوْمِكُمَا بِمِصْرَ بُيُوتًا
>   (Dual-plural): Both of you( Musa and Harun?) settle your people in Egypt in houses

then it moves further and says:

> َاجْعَلُواْ بُيُوتَكُمْ قِبْلَةً وَأَقِيمُواْ الصَّلَوةَ
>   (Plural 3+): and make your houses [facing the] qiblah and establish prayer

before ending by addressing single person:

> وَبَشِّرِ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ
>   and (You -singular-) give good tidings to the believers.

This seems like the first part of the verse addresses Musa () and Harun () (his brother), the second part seems to address a group Musa, Harun and their people? or only the followers of Musa() and Harun ()? And the last part seems to address a single person, but who is it Musa ()?

How is this verse interpreted in tafsir books and who are the addressee's of each part?

Comment: All of the tafseers I checked ([here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=745&idto=745&bk_no=49&ID=757) 
and [here](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1321&idto=1321&bk_no=61&ID=1334)) didn't take "who are the addressee's ?" as an issue, and it seems that they assumed **as you and I assumed(Musa and Harun, Musa Group, Musa alone)**, except of [this source](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura10-aya87.html), he assumed the last one is Muhammad PBUH not Musa PBUH